# My update panel doesn't unblock

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, block, panel

I have a big method that parses an excel document. In order to parse the whole excel it needs around 10 minutes for now (yes is a very big excel document with a lot of sheets). The method is called when the user select a specific value from a dropdownlist. I am using the following block function in order to block a panel to show the user that the parsing is processing.

```
 function lockGridUI() {
        $('#<%=UpdPnl_RevReports.ClientID%>').block({
            message: $('<img src="../Images/loaders/load.gif"/>')

        });
```

The problem is that if my excel document needs more than 4 minutes in order to be parsed my panel remains blocked forever!! I have set a time out unblock function and is working but i dont want to add a timeout in order to unblock my panel because i dont know the time that the excel needs in order to be parsed.

I have try the following from code behind:

```
 string sScript = "";
    sScript = sScript + "function unlockUI() {";
    sScript = sScript + @"$('#<%=UpdPnl_RevReports.ClientID%>').unblock();" ;
    sScript = sScript + "}";


    // REGISTER NOW.
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Registered Script", sScript, true);
```

Unfortunately with no luck! I have called the javascript function from the code behind at the end of the method but still no luck.

I dont know why the panel remains blocked even if my method finish.

Could you please suggest something?

Comment: Does a user expect some result from processing? It is better to return a "ticket" to a user immediately and put processing to background. At the end of the process save result with ticket to a DB or file. The user then can check the result using their ticket.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in code-behind:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Registered script", string.Format("$('#{0}').unblock();", UpdPnl_RevReports.ClientID), true);
```

You can also increase the timeout for asynchronous postbacks in the ScriptManager:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="1800" />
```

Comment: Sorry no luck again!

Comment: Can we see (in the question) the event handler where this code is called? And the way the lengthy processing is initiated in code-behind, if it is not in the same function?

Comment: I call the function exactly before my method exists. When i add a breakpoint i can see that it actually passes from this code and then the method is exists.

Comment: I added another suggestion to my answer.

Comment: what do you mean to increase the asynchronous postbacks? I dont know how this is working ..

Comment: I showed the markup for the ScriptManager, with the AsyncPostBackTimeout set to 1800 seconds (the default is 90 seconds). You can modify your markup accordingly.

Comment: You were right about the second option. I increase the AsyncPostBackTimeout because i had a long request and is perfectly working. Thanks for your time.